# Hash a double in Java

Tags: java, object, double, hashcode, primitive-types

I was wondering how to hash a double in Java? I have hashed other primitive data and objects. I thought I could use the hashcode method? From what I have seen this looks quite complex. I came across something about creating a seed.

I was wondering any ideas on how to go about this. Hoping to put in with the rest of my hashcode for the class that has the double?

I was wondering if there are issues with me trying to hash arraylists, arrays and other objects in java. Some of my classes contain arraylists.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`Double.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#hashCode%28%29) complex? It basically converts `double` into a `long` (no magic here, after all they both are simply 64-bit values in memory) and computing `long` hash is quite simple. The `double` -> `long` conversion is done via [`public static doubleToLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29). What is complex about this?

## Examples:

```
Double.valueOf(42.5).hashCode();        //better answer to everything

Long.valueOf(Double.doubleToLongBits(42.5)).hashCode();
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, i tried the hashcode on the double and got the following message cannot be dereferenced. I am running hashcode() method on a getClassMethod() i.e this.getClassMethod().hashCode(); The getClassMethod returns the double.

Comment: @daveb: have a look at examples I just added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Thomasz,  I did int hash6 = Double.valueOf(this.getClassMethod()).hashCode(); and it compiled without the previous problem. Is the line of code okay to you? Cheers DaveB

Comment: The short answer is "don't hash doubles (or floats)".  Hashing floating point numbers will not give you reasonable results because of the limits of precision. For instance [`a = 1d/3d;`] followed by [`b = (a * 2 + 1) / 2 - 0.5d;`] will give you different answers as doubles, even though in a perfect world they would be the same.

Comment: @Phil I second that. Folks hitting this page will see the answer above and take it as a solution where in fact it would break in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need this for, you could go with a very simple approach of just mod(ing) it.

```
 int hash(double d) {
   return d % 71; //use a prime number here
 }
```

If it is just for storing a few doubles in a hash, this should do it.
If you want to spread the hash, just increase the "71"

Comment: This is a poor hash, it will return the same value for doubles close to each other. And what if your program only needs doubles between 0 and 1? Constant hash.

Comment: I am hashing up all the fields of the diff classes, and overriding hashcode, equals and to string for all my classes. So that I can compare objects from them and also make sure that objects are unique as well. I have been using 31 prime number and concatenating the hashcodes into 1. My double is for a price of an item. DaveB

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz totally agree!  That's why I started with "depending on what you need this for".  If you "knew" your values were all between 0 and 1 you should use something else.

Comment: -1 this is an extremely poor hash function. It removes the fractional part completely. And in addition, it maps all numbers onto only 71 different ones.

Comment: @fishinear, if you read my comment above yours, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

The way Java does it is to convert the raw bit of a double into a long.

```
// from Double.
public static long doubleToLongBits(double value) {
    long result = doubleToRawLongBits(value);
    // Check for NaN based on values of bit fields, maximum
    // exponent and nonzero significand.
    if ( ((result & DoubleConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) ==
          DoubleConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) &&
         (result & DoubleConsts.SIGNIF_BIT_MASK) != 0L)
        result = 0x7ff8000000000000L;
    return result;
}

public int hashCode() {
    long bits = doubleToLongBits(value);
    return (int)(bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
}
```

Note: There many values of NaN (and two types) but Java treats them as all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

```
int h2 = new Double(area).hashCode();
```