# Why HashSet is sorted?

Tags: java, integer, hashset

I am learning about containers in Java and I've read recently that HashSet doesn't give the elements in order. What's interesting for **Integer** my randomly made HashSet is sorted. When I changed its type to **Double** the printed HashSet was sorted no more. My question is: does HashSet work differently for various types then?

Comment: It depends on the hash codes.

Comment: Do not rely on the order of a hashset. Anything you find is purely coincidental by dint of whatever code & hashing function is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @CollinD I just made a for loop and put 10 000 elements in the HashSet using random.nextInt();

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that is related to what I said.

Comment: I mean, i don't understand why hashing function works differently for Integer and Double?

Comment: The docs for `HashSet` indicates it is backed by a `HashMap`. The entire public contract of the `HashMap` can be read at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashSet` uses a `HashMap` internally. `HashMap` stores its elements in a hash table using each Object's `hashCode()` method.

For `int` and `double`, these are [auto-boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into the `Integer` and `Double` classes. When you make a `HashSet` of `int`s, it uses [Integer's hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()) method, which just returns the `int`. So if you add `int`s, they get stored sorted. But for `double`, [Double's hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#hashCode()) method is much more complicated, because of the way doubles are represented in memory.

Comment: This is only true for certain small ranges of integer values.

Answer (score 1):

When hashing double, Java converts it to long since they both are simply 64-bit values in memory.

You can actually experiment the hashcode to see how it works for integer and double.

Check this for more details: [Hash a double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650798/hash-a-double-in-java)